# Pylance (ReportMissingImport) in Vs code

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, dependencies, interpreter

I have a problem with python on vs code, after installing numpy and matplotlib in venv, and the environment is activated, with all dependencies listed when i run pip list in cmd,

I have created another venv to resolve problem still no way, I need assistance

[numpy not recognized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVSjA.png)

[output error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZnGL.png)

Comment: Please add code and error messages as text, never as image.  It's the main reason why new users aren't yet allowed to add inline images.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your bottom vs code bar there should be a python word followed by the version you would be using, if you click this, a pop up will appear asking what Python interpreter you would like to use.
[image: vscode bottom bar]

Try to look for your venv interpreter, select it.

[image: Select Python interpreter pop-up]

And vs code will now detect your dependencies correctly.
It will create a file named `settings.json` in a new directory `.vscode` inside your project. This should (in my opinion) not be commited.